# Function prototype not found in LLVM pass

Tags: llvm

In LLVM Pass when I want add new code that uses a function from a header file.
Since the function is not used in the source code its prototype is removed by clang.  So my pass tries look for the function definition from the module, it returns.
How can I use such function in code generation??
I am using LLVM-3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can add a stub function, that calls your prototype, so it wouldn't get deleted. In this case your pass would need to delete this stub function.

Another way - just build definition of your prototype using C++ API. Of course, it's possible only if your prototype isn't changing.